# copying variable range of cells from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 12 sheets with information within them. Certain information I want to collate from each sheet onto one sheet.

So,

I first of all find out how many rows I am dealing with, then I want to copy the first two columns into another sheet (Results).

Now I can get the first column to copy across from each sheet but a cannot workout what im doing wrong to get the second column copied aswell.

```
Sub loopMe()

Dim Jan As Worksheet, Feb As Worksheet, Mar As Worksheet, Apr As Worksheet, May As Worksheet, Jun As Worksheet
Dim Jul As Worksheet, Aug As Worksheet, Sep As Worksheet, October As Worksheet, Nov As Worksheet, Dec As Worksheet
Dim LstR As Long, rngJan As Range, c As Range, rngFeb As Range, rngMar As Range, rngApr As Range
Dim rngMay As Range, rngJun As Range, rngJul As Range, rngAug As Range, rngSep As Range, rngOctober As Range
Dim rngNov As Range, rngDec As Range


Set Jan = Sheets("January")                                       'set the sheet to loop
With Jan                                                         'do something with the sheet
    LstR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row               'find last row
    Set rngJan = .Range("A2:B" & LstR)                           'set range to loop
End With

Set Feb = Sheets("February")                                       'set the sheet to paste
With Feb                                                         'do something with the sheet
    LstR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row               'find last row
    Set rngFeb = .Range("A2:B" & LstR)                           'set range to loop
End With
```

' The above should set the range of data in each sheet (I hope)
' Then I run the following

```
For Each y In rngJan
    Worksheets("Results").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = y.Value
Next y


For Each y In rngFeb
    Worksheets("Results").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = y.Value
Next y
```

The information I need are stored in columns A & B so they are what im trying to copy across.

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First you only want to loop through column A.

Then set the ranges to two columns, the source is easy as declaring the range with y and y.offset.  The target use resize(,2).

```
Sub loopMe()

Dim Jan As Worksheet, Feb As Worksheet, Mar As Worksheet, Apr As Worksheet, May As Worksheet, Jun As Worksheet
Dim Jul As Worksheet, Aug As Worksheet, Sep As Worksheet, October As Worksheet, Nov As Worksheet, Dec As Worksheet
Dim LstR As Long, rngJan As Range, c As Range, rngFeb As Range, rngMar As Range, rngApr As Range
Dim rngMay As Range, rngJun As Range, rngJul As Range, rngAug As Range, rngSep As Range, rngOctober As Range
Dim rngNov As Range, rngDec As Range


Set Jan = Sheets("January")                                       'set the sheet to loop
With Jan                                                         'do something with the sheet
    LstR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row               'find last row
    Set rngJan = .Range("A2:A" & LstR)                           'set range to loop
End With

Set Feb = Sheets("February")                                       'set the sheet to paste
With Feb                                                         'do something with the sheet
    LstR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row               'find last row
    Set rngFeb = .Range("A2:A" & LstR)                           'set range to loop
End With
' The above should set the range of data in each sheet (I hope) ' Then I run the following

For Each y In rngJan
    Worksheets("Results").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).resize(,2).Value = Range(y, y.Offset(, 1)).Value
Next y


For Each y In rngFeb
    Worksheets("Results").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).resize(,2).Value = Range(y, y.Offset(, 1)).Value
Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: @JasonPye Did this help?  If not please give feed back so I may better help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for an efficient use of the `For...Next` statement,  avoiding the excessive use of object variables. It clears previous data before proceeding to copy data, also includes an error handling in case the worksheet was deleted or it's expected name changed. Tried to make it self explanatory with comments in the code, nevertheless do let me know of any question you may have.

```
Sub Copy_Months_Data()
Const kRowIni As Byte = 2   'Constant to hold the starting row, easy to update if required
Dim aMonths As Variant
aMonths = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", _
    "May", "June", "July", "August", _
    "September", "October", "November", "December")
Dim WshSrc As Worksheet, WshTrg As Worksheet
Dim rSrc As Range
Dim lRowLst As Long, lRowNxt As Long
Dim vItm As Variant

    On Error GoTo ErrHdlr

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Application.EnableEvents = 0

    With ThisWorkbook 'Procedure is resident in data workbook
    'With Workbooks(WbkName) 'Procedure is no resident in data workbook

        Rem Set & Prepare Target Worksheet - Results
        vItm = "Results"
        Set WshTrg = .Sheets(vItm)    'Change sheet name as required
        With WshTrg
            Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
            Rem Clear Prior Data
            .Columns("A:B").ClearContents
            lRowNxt = kRowIni
        End With

        For Each vItm In aMonths

            Rem Set Source Worksheet - Each month
            Set WshSrc = .Sheets(vItm)
            With WshSrc
                Rem Set Last Row for Columns A & B
                lRowLst = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                If .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row > lRowLst Then _
                    lRowLst = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                Set rSrc = .Range(.Cells(kRowIni, 1), .Cells(lRowLst, 2))
            End With

            Rem Copy Range Values to Target Worksheet
            With rSrc
                WshTrg.Cells(lRowNxt, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value2
                lRowNxt = lRowNxt + .Rows.Count
            End With

    Next: End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
    Application.EnableEvents = 1

Exit Sub
ErrHdlr:
    MsgBox prompt:="Process failed while processing worksheet """ & vItm & """ due to: " & vbLf & _
        vbTab & "Err: " & Err.Number & vbLf & _
        vbTab & "Dsc: " & Err.Description, _
        Buttons:=vbCritical + vbApplicationModal, _
        Title:="Copy Months Data"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
    Application.EnableEvents = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Get the error: Process failed while processing worksheet "February" due to: Err:1004 Dsc Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: Need more info, can't do anything with that statement. 1) What line gives the error? 2) It's your sheet named `February`? 2) It's the procedure resident in data workbook?

Comment: I run the code above, but when it loops around "With WshSrc" drops out when its looking at February on this line: Set rSrc = Range(.Cells(kRowIni, 1), .Cells(lRowLst, 2))

Comment: add a period `.` before `Range`